# Laravel eloquent save not update field with double value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a problem, laravel eloquent not save the updated fields when i call save function there is my example :

```php
    $user->solde = $user->solde + 2000;
    $user->save();
```

the solde field is a double type in database, eloquent not fire event on update solde.

Comment: please share complete code

Comment: pls share your `solde` migration

Comment: solde value is 745600.87 (Laravel show the value as 7.5E+5) and when i add 2000 to it, laravel show 7.5E+5 again, and eloquent not see the value to be updated

Answer (score 2):

Use `strval()`:

```
$user->solde = strval($user->solde + 2000);
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with changing php ini precision to 12.